# Ember action sent from index controller not handled by index route

Tags: ember.js

https://emberjs.jsbin.com/depoxiseve/edit?js,output

When observing model changing on the controller, sending an action from an index controller doesn't get handled by the index route. It throws an action not handled error. It would get handled in the application route. Why is this? Is it because index route isn't active yet? Is there any way to get this to work?

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  actions: {
    test: function() {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  test: function() {
    this.send('test');
  }.observes('model')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well JSBin seems to be broken at the moment, but I think if you want the action to bubble, you'd need to create a `test` action on your controller, then `return true` from the action. Because `this.send('test');` will send a test action to `this`, which is in fact the controller.

So:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  },
  actions: {
    test: function() {
      console.log('test');
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  test: function() {
    this.send('test');
  }.observes('model'),
  actions: {
    test: function() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

P.S. What are you trying to do? It's generally recommended to avoid observers if possible nowadays (performance issues it seems).

Comment: That didn't work in JS Bin, and I'm seeing this issue locally as well.

Comment: Also, I did find another way to do it, but this issue still confuses me.

Comment: Wondering why you would post an answer that is "I think". There is no reason you should need to define an action on the controller. That's precisely the meaning of bubbling. The problem lies elsewhere.